# Passing files to application jar in spark in yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

I use the following command to deploy my spark application in yarn-cluster mode

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class com.rocai.controller.Controller --jars <absolute-path-to-ojdbc6.jar> --driver-memory 1g --executor-memory 1g --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 2 <absolute-path-to-app.jar> <absolute-path-to-controller.xml>
```

controller.xml is an argument to app.jar. I always end up with a file not found exception for the controller.xml file. I even tried to pass the controller.xml file using the --files tags like so

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class com.rocai.controller.Controller --jars <absolute-path-to-ojdbc6.jar> --driver-memory 1g --executor-memory 1g --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 2 <absolute-path-to-app.jar> <absolute-path-to-controller.xml> --files <absolute-path-to-controller.xml>
```

It's probably because the controller.xml file is not getting uploaded to the application container. I understand that the driver process in yarn-cluster mode will start in any arbitrary node in the cluster. Looking at the logs I see that app.jar, ojdbc6.jar, hadoop_conf.zip and spark-assembly.jars are getting uploaded to the container. How do I ensure that the controller.xml file also gets uploaded to the yarn container?

I might be misunderstanding something here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As a possible WA, you could package your `.xml` file as a jar and refer to it via resource location.

Comment: That would involve rebuilding the app.jar each time I have a new controller file which is not feasible for me. Yarn-client mode works perfectly fine though. I was wondering if this is a feature that is not available for spark-submit in the yarn-cluster mode.

Comment: No need to rebuild. You can just add it as yet another jar to the classpath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Spark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#external-datasets), your application can open files locally provided each node has a copy of the file and in the same absolute path.

As for uploading the file when submitting the application, I think you have to pass the `--files` argument before the jar when submitting, so something like this:

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--class com.rocai.controller.Controller \
--jars <absolute-path-to-ojdbc6.jar> \
--driver-memory 1g \
--executor-memory 1g \
--num-executors 2 \
--executor-cores 2 \
--files <absolute-path-to-controller.xml> \
<absolute-path-to-app.jar> <absolute-path-to-controller.xml>
```

However, when your controller xml is uploaded, it will get uploaded in the ../.sparkStaging/applicationId/... folder on HDFS. In other words, the absolute path you pass to the jar as an argument is no longer valid, even though the file has been uploaded. You have to programmatically fetch the path to where it's been uploaded. I believe you can use the [SparkFiles](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$) class for this, though I haven't used it myself.

Another workaround would be to manually upload the controller xml to a fixed path on HDFS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the order of how the parameters must be passed to spark-submit! I was already using the --files parameter but after passing my app.jar parameters. The required files are now getting uploaded to the yarn application container. I'm not passing the absolute path of the controller.xml file to the application jar though, just the name. The SparkContext picks up the required file as all resources are available in the same container as the application jar.

Comment: Glad to help. I also ran into this problem some time back. In my case, Spark wasn't able to find my Hive metastore and the problem was that I was passing `hive-site.xml` via the `--files` parameter but after the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of reference, below is the command that I used to execute the spark job

```
spark-submit \
--class com.rocai.controller.Controller \ 
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--jars /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/ojdbc6.jar,\
/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,\
/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,\
/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar \
--files controller.xml,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml \
--driver-memory 1g --executor-memory 1G --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 1 \
app.jar \
controller.xml
```

It seems its necessary to include the datanucleus jars and hive-site.xml in order to avoid a 'Class Not Found' Exception. Also make sure that there are no spaces between comma separated values.